# Swift Assign Image If string == 'Something'

Tags: ios, json, uiimage

Im trying to write a Swift iOS application that displays one of four images based on the outcome of a API JSON Response.

I have 4 images in the Xcode project, defined as:

```
let crossStatus: UIImage = UIImage(named:"cross-circle")!;
let exclamationStatus: UIImage = UIImage(named:"exclamation")!;
let informationStatus: UIImage = UIImage(named:"information")!;
let tickStatus: UIImage = UIImage(named:"tick-circle")!;
```

The app makes an API request and gets back JSON of:

services{current-events{id: "up", image: "image.url.location"}}

I have services as an NSDictionary and current-events as another inside that, when I make a NSURL out of 'image' and pop the NSURL into the cell the page works as expected, but I want to be able to load the local images pending the response of 'id'.

The code for the IF is:

```
let statusID = rowData["id"] as? String;
let imgData : UIImage = crossStatus;
if (statusID == "up") {
    let imgData : UIImage = tickStatus;
}
if (statusID == "warning") {
    let imgData : UIImage = exclamationStatus;
}
if (statusID == "down") {
    let imgData : UIImage = crossStatus;
}
else {
    let imgData : UIImage = exclamationStatus;
}
```

When I run the code now, the crossStatus image is called but 90% of the services are either up or warning, so I know the placeholder is working but now the changing of the variable.

Where am I going wrong?
Thanks
Mathew

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you keep redeclaring `imgData` as a local variable such that the `imgData` constant in your conditionals isn't the same as the `imgData` constant outside of your conditional; so your original `imgData` object is never changed. You have to make the original `imgData` a variable then update it instead, ex:

```
let statusID = rowData["id"] as? String;
var imgData : UIImage = crossStatus;
if (statusID == "up") {
    imgData = tickStatus;
} else if (statusID == "warning") {
    imgData = exclamationStatus;
} else if (statusID == "down") {
    imgData = crossStatus;
} else {
    imgData = exclamationStatus;
}
```

Note: It's not necessary for you to initialize `imgData` before your conditionals, but I've left it since it's in your original code.

And you probably meant for your 2nd and 3rd if statements to be `else if` statements, so I've updated to account for that.

Comment: ok, so : let imgData : UIImage = crossStatus; is where the static string isn't expected to change and var imgData : UIImage = crossStatus; is where it is?

Comment: The other problem is that because of the `else` imgData will be either `crossStatus` or `exclamationStatus`. With any `statusID` that is not `crossStatus ` the result will be `exclamationStatus`.

Comment: `let` declares a constant so it can't change.

Comment: @Zaph Good point. I'm not entirely sure of the OP's intention, but he probably meant else if. Updated.

Comment: I was trying to do a catch all but dont think its relevant, so the new code is:             
'let statusID = rowData["id"] as? String;
            var imgData : UIImage = crossStatus;
            if (statusID == "up") {
                imgData = tickStatus;
            }
            if (statusID == "warning") {
                imgData = exclamationStatus;
            }
            if (statusID == "down") {
                imgData = crossStatus;
            }'
but it defaults back to 'crossStatus'

Comment: @MathewJenkinson OK, that's fine. But you should still probably do `else if `... Not that it will make a huge difference, but it means that your app won't have to take the time to check each conditional even after the correct if statement is executed.